# Android web app - php with local database

Tags: php, javascript, android, database, offline

I have a very simple web page in PHP that uses a MySQL database to randomly feed a simple quiz that goes on forever as long as the user wants to keep answering questions.

I want to move this to my Android to be able to use it offline. I used jQuery Mobile to adapt the layouts to the smartphone. So now I want to move the database to a local database and remove all the need to an internet connection. I have absolutely no experience on Android development so if anyone can help me with a few questions, I'd appreciate it:

- How can I store my existing database in the smartphone?
- The only actions that the app performs on the database are selects. The information on the database will grow with time (not much, I just want to be able to add more records with time). Is there any tool I can use to manage the local database and add the information as I need (as I do now with PhpMyAdmin)?
- The web page exists online right now, will I be able to run it locally as it is? (aka, PHP page with css and js files)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1) Android databases are done in SQLite. I'm unsure exactly what the syntax difference between mySQL and SQLite is, but if a straight dump/import doesn't work, you could export to csv/import that way. For info on getting an external database packaged with an app, check [Using your own SQLite database with Android applications.](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/) It's a very helpful guide to getting it set up.

2) I use a Firefox add-on, [SQLiteManager](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/). I hate doing it, as it's the only reason I have Firefox installed any more, but on *nix it's the best option I've found. It's either that, command line, or SQLiteMan, which I found feature-lacking. On other platforms, I can't comment.

3) I don't know if PHP has a good library for SQLite. If so, you'll most likely need to do some modification to work with that instead of mySQL. If you can get that running smoothly, you should be able to drop it into a webview. The other option is to redo it in Java.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, I already changed from MySQL to SQLite and I'm using a local file for my database. Now I need to remove this from the web environment and have it run locally on my Android. I can't run the local PHP file directly on the phone and I can't seem to be able to open the it on the browser. So, is there any way or any place I can see how to do this last step? Thanks!

Comment: Oh, the server-side stuff. Right, well it's probably not going to be very speedy, but you can try [PHP for Android](http://phpforandroid.net/). I haven't used it, so can't say how friendly it is.